# Java type inference: why does this compile?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Using Java 17, with Hamcrest 2.2

```java
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

// snip

String m = "something";
JsonNode j = new TextNode("something else");
MatcherAssert.assertThat(j, Matchers.is(m)); // expected compile error here
```

I expect this to cause a compilation error. `MatcherAssert.assertThat` and `Matchers.is` have the following signatures:

```java
public static <T> void assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher);
public static <T> org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> is(T value);
```

so, the code should break down to

```java
String m = "something";
JsonNode j = new TextNode("something else");
Matcher<String> matcher = Matchers.is(m);  // specify static type
MatcherAssert.assertThat(j, matcher);      // actual compilation error
```

which fails because `String` is not a super type of `JsonNode`.

Instead, when `Matchers.is(m)` is inlined, it returns `Matcher<Object>` which binds `<T>` in `MatcherAssert.assertThat` to `Object` and causes compilation to pass (though as expected, the assertion fails since a `JsonNode` can not `equals` a `String`).

I don't get why `Matchers.is(m)` binds `<T>` to `Object`.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javac looks at the line and resolves repeatedly, filling in the blank like its doing a puzzle. Specifically, the `assertThat` line requires some typevar binding; the method call involves a type variable `<T>`. I shall call this one `<A>` to differentiate it from the completely separate type var that the `is` method has.

`<A>` needs to be figured out. No explicit choice is made (you called `MatcherAssert.assertThat`; you did not call `MatcherAssert.<String>assertThat`). Thus, time to infer.

Let's check what hints are available. The first parameter is of type T, and the argument passed is `JsonNode`.

You'd think - oh great, so, T is JsonNode. Not so fast. If I have a method with signature `void foo(Number n)`, I can pass an integer to it. Saying that the type of the expression insta-binds the typevar means that T could never be an interface type in the first place, and any subtyping is likely to break stuff, even inconsequential subtyping such as `new ArrayList<String>() {}` (note those braces there), or any lambda.

No, it binds T to the range `[Object ... JsonNode]`. It's like `? super JsonNode`. If T ends up being `Object`, that's fine. an expression of type `JsonNode` is a valid parameter when the parameter requires an `Object`.

If type inference ends here, javac will take the most specific type in the range it found, and *would* bind to JsonNode. We can see that in action with this different example:

```
public static <T> T ident(T in) { return in; }

var x = ident(new JsonNode());
x.someMethodOnlyJsonNodeHas();
```

The above compiles fine and runs without issue. `var x` will 'bind' var to be the type of the expression, and the type is `JsonNode`. Because of the process as outlined above: While inferencing T, T is constrained, by way of the `new JsonNode()`, to `[Object .. JsonNode]` and no further constraints apply, so javac picks the most specific thing it can.

But, `assertThat` has more parameters that involve `<A>`. We must keep looking. We have a second argument, and its type is required to be `Matcher<? super A>`. The expression we find there is `Matchers.is(m)` which is a bit funky - we're trying to figure out what `<A>` is and in the middle of doing that, we now have to figure out what `<B>` is (`<B>` is what we shall call the `<T>` in `public static <T> Matcher<T> is (T value);`, because these typevars are entirely independent, the fact that both use T is pure coincidence and has no bearing whatsoever on inference. Renaming one of these should not matter and indeed it doesn't). And to figure out what `<B>` is, javac will.. infer from context.

So, while 'going from the outside in' during the process of inferring `<A>`, we need to infer inside-out to figure out `<B>`. Hopefully this helps a lot in highlighting why inference can produce some bizarre results sometimes, and why you might just want to rewrite this code with an explicit `Matcher<String> matcher = Matchers.is(m)`, just to avoid this kind of very tricky analysis.

Point is, java can't do that, it can't go both ways at the same time and violate the basics of cause and effect.

So, instead, `Matchers.is(m)` is resolved on its own, without the context of what's around it. `m` is a string, the signature of `is()` is very simple. `<B>` is constrained to be `[Object .. String]`.

Now we can go back to resolving `<A>`.

We have one parameter that constrains `<A>` to be `[Object .. JsonNode]`, and another parameter that constrains `<A>` to be `[Object .. String]`.

And.. we're done! There are no further restrictions, and no need to figure out overloads, so, we can now coalesce our restrictions.

Thus, javac does what it always does and picks the most specific type that fits all restrictions. Which is `Object`. Object works fine here:

```
Matcher<Object> matcher = Matchers.is("Hello");
```

compiles just fine. Try it. Why wouldn't that be fine? So, that works with `T = Object`. And `j`, being of type `JsonNode`, that works too:

```
Object o = new JsonNode():
```

compiles and works fine. Try it. Why wouldn't that be fine?

Hence, all is fine. The compiler compiles this and runs it as written without giving you any errors or warnings.

Semantically it makes sense too. For the same reason the `contains` method of `java.util.List` accepts any `Object` instead of `E` - "Does this list of oranges contain this apple?" is a question that makes sense and has a sensible, if rather obvious, answer: No, it does not.

In contrast to: "Here is an apple. Add it to this list of oranges" which does not make sense. The same thing is happening here: Please check that this JsonNode passes this matcher of strings. Fail the test if it does not.

This, too, is a semantically valid question with an obvious answer: It never will. The answer is 'no they aren't equal' and we know it before even running the code. But the compiler isn't aware that this is what the `assertThat` method is for, and that any line of code that makes an assertion that is *guaranteed* to fail, is better off being a compiler warning. Short of turning javac into some sort of endlessly pluggable editor kit thing (which would be awesome! But it is not, and no programming language I know of is), there's no way for javac to know that `assertThat` comes with the baggage of: "This call is useless if all paths through it necessarily lead to a failed result", nor even that `Matcher<String>` objects come with the baggage that they are *guaranteed* to fail when asked to match an object of type `JsonNode`. Javac can't know that without running this code and you really don't want your compiler to run your code halfway through compiling it. There's the halting problem to think of, for starters.